# Why are #define and typedef operands inverted?

Tags: c, typedef, c-preprocessor

The following defines `A` to be *replaced* by `B`:

```
#define A B
```

Whereas this defines `A` to be an alias for the *type* `B`:

```
typedef B A;
```

Why ? Isn't this incoherent ?

Comment: PS : I know they are totally different and used for very different purposes. But personally, I think typedef should have been the other way around.

Comment: if it's any consolation, Ken Thompson kind of thinks the same thing. In Go, although there's no direct equivalent to `typedef` that creates just a type alias, the way to create a new type from an old one is `type NewType OldType`. I wonder if he and Dennis Ritchie would argue head-to-head the syntax decisions that Go explicitly makes similar-to-but-different-from C. Declaration order in Go is basically "the other way around" :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply put: consider the following variable declarations:

```
// declare a variable called "myInt" with type int
int myInt;
// declare a variable called "myDouble" with type double
double myDouble;
// declare a variable called "myLong" with type long
long myLong;
// declare a variable called "myFunc" with type pointer to function
void (*myFunc)(char*);
```

Then the `typedef`s make perfect sense:

```
// declare a type alias called "myInt" with type int
typedef int myInt;
// declare a type alias called "myDouble" with type double
typedef double myDouble;
// declare a type alias called "myLong" with type long
typedef long myLong;
// declare a type alias called "myFunc" with type pointer to function
typedef void (*myFunc)(char*);
```

Macros, on the other hand, can take on a function-style syntax:

```
#define A(B, C) B, C

A(1, 2) // expands out to 1, 2
```

So for macros, the "definition" coming after the "name" makes more sense.

(This applies to C++ too, by the way.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, macros are pretty much a mess.

`typedef` was added to the language quite a while after most of the rest of the language was complete. It uses the same syntax as a storage class:

```
static int x;
extern int y;
typedef int z;
```

These define `x`, `y` and `z` as all being `int` -- the difference is that `x` and `y` are objects of type `int`, and `z` is basically an alias for `int` itself.

As such, `typedef` fits with the language proper reasonably well, and it's (as usual) the preprocessor that's really the "odd man out." At the same time, you could argue that the rest of the language should change as well. Just for an obvious example, Pascal roughly reversed the order of things:

```
type
    z = integer;

var
    x : integer;
```

While it doesn't make a lot of difference for trivial examples, I think this is rather simpler to read, especially when you deal with more complex declarations. For better or worse, however, Pascal has (mostly) fallen out of favor, and newer languages like Java have retained this particular part of C syntax (i.e., the part of C they kept was the one thing most in need of being changed).

Comment: +1: Good to remember the notion of a keyword to declare declarations. Always, always think twice before introducing a language construct invoked by syntactic order alone, without a keyword/operator.

Comment: Why do you say macros (implied the C pre-processor) are a mess? Is it completely different for some aspects compared to the C language? Absolutely (e.g. late binding compared to early binding). Can it be hard to learn fully? Yes it can. But is is a mess? Not that I can see. So could you elaborate what you mean by "mess"?

Comment: @hlovdal: A few of the most obvious problems are: 1) lack of scoping, 2) information unavailable to debuggers, 3) extremely error prone (e.g., multiply evaluated arguments). They are *rarely* the best solution available.

Comment: 1) The lack of scoping applies to macro languages in general, do you then consider all macro languages messy? 2) True. But this then "only" makes the code hard to debug, it does not make the code messy. 3) This can also by all means be said about the C language itself (i.e. "if (i = 0) ...", the default of no break in switch statements, etc).

Comment: Maybe we put different meanings into the word "messy", but I consider something messy if there is lack of order and consistency, and that it is difficult to get an overview and to modify. Macros might very well contribute to that, but it is not so that it will automatically do so (which is what I am hearing you saying).  Using macros will introduce an additional level of indirection which means increased complexity, but assumedly the macro itself will also bring some additional benefit that outweigh the added complexity. Thus: Macros are neutral, not bad.

Answer (score 2):

Because `A` in `typedef` can be multiple symbols, e.g. `typedef int Integer, *PInteger;`.
This is consistent with how variables are defined (`int var, *pvar;`).

Answer (score 2):

Typedef is from a language syntax point of view in the `storage class specifier` group together with `extern` and `static`(*), and thus typedef has the same placement as those. It does not obviously belong to this group, but I guess it was probably where it was least mis-placed.

(*)
Storage class also includes `auto` and `register`, but nobody uses those any more.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why as far as the language decisions are concerned, but the way typedef is makes sense to me.

The `typedef` specifier is part of the language.  It serves as a way to alias a type to some name.  You could always inline what the type is in a variable declaration.

```
struct arr { int len; char *chars; } name;
struct arr another_name;
```

Using `typedef` mirrors this use except instead of declaring a variable to the type, you're declaring a name for the type.

```
typedef struct { int len; char *chars; } arr;
arr name;
arr another_name;
```

The `#define` directive is part of the preprocessor and not of the language so it isn't bound to the way the language represents certain constructs and can use the more natural way of declaring it.

Answer (score 1):

Because the pre-processor and the compiler are in fact two different programs, each with its own syntax. One could combine the preprocessor with other languages with not too much difficulty (I actually did that in older times by using `cpp` on dBase III programs and on AutoLISP because these languages lacked a good include mechanism for constants).
As others have already pointed out, `typedef` follows the syntax of the declaration system of C and `#define` is a simple straight-forward declaration of substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, typedef syntax tends to throw me off a little as well.  I assume that your question is more of a complaint - C is almost 40 years old, you do not expect the typedef syntax to change, do you?